# Remove what is after @ into an email?

Tags: php

Let's say I have some email: **some_email@yahoo.com**.

Firstly I would want to remove everything that is after **@**.

And last remove anything inside what's left from the previous action what matches the special characters allowed in an email address format ( anything like "_", "." or other special characters allowed ) and camile hump the first letter in the word or words if that's the case.

Is it possible and how would I do that ?

Comment: No problem, it isn't so different from PHP.

Comment: If you just wanted to check if it was a valid email, you could use filter_var - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: No, I already have a regex to check if an email is valid, I just want to do something like what @Hasan Khan wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Parse($text)
{
    list($text) = explode('@', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', ' ', $text);
    $text = ucwords($text);
    return $text;
}
```

For your input some_email@yahoo.com, it gives output 'Some Email'

Live action http://codepad.org/w0yfRFbo

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$str= "abc_abc@xyz.com";
$part = explode('@',$str);
$left_part = $part[0];
$left_part = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -%][().][\/]/s', '', $left_part);
echo $left_part;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter($mail){

    $exp    = explode('@',$mail);
    $char   = array('.','_','-');
    $new    = str_replace($char, '', $exp[0]);

    return strtolower($new);
}

$mail   = 'some_email.new@yahoo.com';
echo filter($mail);
```